# Visual Studio template for Stream Analytics job?

Tags: cortana-intelligence, azure-stream-analytics

Is there a Visual Studio template for Stream Analytics job? i.e. a concept of develop and publish from Visual Studio to Azure.

If not how do we develop a application lifecycle for Stream analytics?

For example like Azure Data Factory have json templates to create its objects, likewise do Stream analytics have one?

Comment: Based on reply from a Microsoft employee in MSDN forum and based on Azure feedback. Its on the backlog and planned https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/5f252429-19b9-4a8f-9ad2-c948b544f986/visual-studio-template-for-stream-analytics-job?forum=AzureStreamAnalytics

Answer (score 1):

There are couple tutorials from Microsoft:

1. MyDriving solution that has a full ARM template and it does include few ASA jobs in it:
   https://github.com/Azure-Samples/MyDriving/blob/master/scripts/ARM/scenario_complete.json#L266
2. OnClick PowerShell sample with scripts to deploy ASA job:
   https://github.com/Azure/azure-stream-analytics/tree/master/Samples/ASAOneClick

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the way I'm authoring Stream Analytics jobs and job objects (i.e. Inputs, Outputs, Transformations) is using 'hand-made' JSON (i.e. no Intellisense support in Visual Studio) refer here for JSON schema reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn835031.aspx And execute them using Stream Analytics PowerShell cmdlets refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt270341.aspx

We could use a simple console application project or PowerShell project in Visual Studio and bring it under source control.

Answer (score 0):

Steam Analytics has sample json template in ARM template (Azure Resource Manager). You could use it in VisualStudio maybe.

Reference the template from azure documents: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.streamanalytics/streamingjobs

If you need to define the inputs and outputs of the stream analytics job, you may also need to reference the create input/output rest api, since the document lack of this kind of information.